# How to display sender name in group chat

Tags: android, arrays, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a chat app for android with `firebase`. so i want to show the sender name above of the first message from same sender but i get the sender name on every message sent by the sender,

[sender name bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaORr.jpg)

the logic i am using

```
dbRef.child("Group chats").child(chat.getGroupId())
                .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        for (dataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                            val mChat = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat::class.java)
                            val previousChat = if (position > 0) {
                                mChatList[position - 1]
                            } else {
                                mChat
                            }

                            if ( previousChat?.getSender() == mChat?.getSender() ){
                                holder.senderName?.visibility = GONE
                            }
                            else {
                                holder.senderName?.visibility = VISIBLE
                                holder.senderName?.text = chat.getSenderName()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got you know and I have figured it out and is working on my code

**Step 1 . Introduce a function to get the sender for the last chat**

```
 private fun getTheRecentSender(position: Int): String? {
    val lastMessagePosition = position - 1
    //return the 1st message if messages chat thread is empty
    val chat = chatMessageThread[if (lastMessagePosition < 0) 0 else lastMessagePosition]
    //get and return the sender of the last message
    return chat.from
}
```

**Step 2. Compare previous chat sender and hide the name if it is the same sender**

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val viewType = getItemViewType(position)
    val chat = chatMessageThread[position]

    //for incoming chat
    if (viewType == 1) {
        (holder as InComingViewHolder).itemBinding.msg = chat

        //hide sender's name if previous chat came from the same sender
        holder.itemBinding.msgFrom.visibility =
            if (chat.from == getTheRecentSender(position)) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }
    //for outgoing chat
    else {
        (holder as OutGoingViewHolder).itemBinding.msg = chat

        //hide sender's name if previous chat came from the same sender
        holder.itemBinding.msgFrom.visibility =
            if (chat.from == getTheRecentSender(position)) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

This is the snapshot of my screen

[image: screenshot from my app]

Let me now try and simulate this using your code above

Comment: Hey bro @tonnie you are awesome , you solved my problem very easily. Thank you so much  . but it has a little bug that  name is not visible on the very first message. as in the image that i attached in the question sender name is not visible on the most top hello message!

Comment: Hey @Tonnie please try to answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/64857715/14617810

Answer (score 0):

@mr. groot was working on a similar app and achived this on my RecyclerView onBind method

```
//maps data to the children
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolderClass, position: Int) {

    //it is called for each row
    val message = messageDataSet[position]
    holder.fromTextView.text = message.from

    holder.msgTextView.text = message.messageString
    holder.timeStampTextView.text = message.timestamp?.dateToString("hh:mm a E dd-MMM")

}
```

I have Data Class called Message and a list of Message objects called messageDataSet. I have a recyclerView's row layout with textViews as shown below.
[image]

Let me know if this helps

Comment: hey @tonnie i am also working with adapter where the code i provided is into the onBindViewHolder() ,  so what you did is not the real solution i mean the code you shared will display sender's name on every message, suppose there are continuously 3 message from 1 sender then sender name will show on each 3 messages, which is my problem. so the desired solution is that the name will show only on the first message from the 3 messages. you can see the image of my problem that i attached in the question .