# How can I sort chat list by the most recent message?

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I don't know why I got stuck on a problem that the *chatList* is not sorting by the last message time or by the most recent message. I have tried by storing `timestamp` in the database and *orderChildBy* timestamp but it still not working.

This is the way how I created chatList in the `firebaseDatabase`

```
    val timeAgo = Date().time

    val myTimeMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
        myTimeMap["timestamp"] = timeAgo.toString()
        myTimeMap["id"] = friendId

    val friendTimeMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
        friendTimeMap["timestamp"] = timeAgo.toString()
        friendTimeMap["id"] = currentUserID

    val chatListSenderReference = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(currentUserID).child(friendId)
        chatListSenderReference.keepSynced(true)
        chatListSenderReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
              override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
              }
              override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                       if(!p0.exists()){
                             chatListSenderReference.updateChildren(friendTimeMap)
                       }
    val chatListReceiverReference = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(friendId).child(currentUserID)
        chatListReceiverReference.updateChildren(myTimeMap)
        }
    })
```

on retrieving the chatlist in recyclerView

```
 mUsers = ArrayList()
        val userRef = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(currentUserID).orderByChild("timestamp")
        userRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
        {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
            {
                (mUsers as ArrayList).clear()
                snapshot.children.forEach {
                    val userUid = it.key
                    if (userUid != null) {
                        (mUsers as ArrayList).add(User(uid = userUid))
                    }
                }
                retrieveGroupChatList()
                chatListAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                chatListAdapter = context?.let { ChatListAdapter(it, (mUsers as ArrayList<User>), true) }
                recyclerViewChatList.adapter = chatListAdapter
            }
        })
```

this is the picture of database, every time when i send or receive message timestamp get update.

[image: database image]

Answer (score 2):

You should store the timestamp of messages and then use `val chatListSenderReference = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(currentUserID).orderByChild("timestamp")`

Comment: Did you try `val chatListSenderReference = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(currentUserID).orderByChild("timestamp")` after adding timestamp? Hopefully it will resolve your problem.

Comment: yes i tried that while retrieving the data in recyclerView, but nothing happen.

Comment: I forgot to add `friendId`. Try this `val chatListSenderReference = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(currentUserID).child(friendId).orderByChild("timestamp")`

Comment: It will not work bro if we go to the child of currentUserId then there will always fields or data of the friend not a list of users currentUser has talked with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for your case but for my Chat App, I had a list of the message and all I did is to sort the list

```
 //sort method - takes a list to be sorted
private fun sortMessagesByDate(messages: MutableList<Message>) {

    //sort messages by Date
    messages.sortWith(compareBy { it.timestamp })
}
```

Method for looping through the ContactList

```
 // method for obtaining contacts and adding them to the lists
private fun getAllContacts() {
    val currentUserPhoneCredential = auth.currentUser?.phoneNumber!!

    firestore.collection("Contacts")
        .whereNotEqualTo("phoneNumber", currentUserPhoneCredential)
        .get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
        for (doc in querySnapshot) {

            val user = doc.toObject(User::class.java)
 //I have 2 lists one with just the names and another with the User Object
            contactsList.add(user)
            contactsNames.add(user.name!!)

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Then on ListView's Adapter passing in the Names List(contactsNames)

```
 adapter =
        ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, contactsNames)
```

Thereafter when a name is clicked at a specific position the app navigates to the DisplayMessage Fragment taking a UserObject corresponding to the clicked contact.

```
//implement listView onClick
    binding.listView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, i, _ ->


       /*when a name is clicked on the ListView at a specific position the app navigates
        to the DisplayMessage Fragment taking a UserObject corresponding to the
         clicked contact.*/
        findNavController().navigate(ChatFragmentDirections
                                         .actionChatFragmentToMessageFragment(contactsList[i]))

    }
```

You could also use a RecyclerView to display the names of the contacts.

Comment: this way you sort messages!? not the chatlist.

Comment: hey tonnie can you please tell me how did you made the chatlist for your chat app (chat list means the list of people current user has chatted with.)

Comment: Hello @Mr. Groot, for this I will have to refer you to my project GIT Repo and have included comments on the code. Follow this link and will see the ChatFragment which has the code for the ChatList https://github.com/Fanadezz/WhatsAppClone/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/androidshowtime/whatsappclone

Comment: Tonnie sorry but i did not find any code for chat-list there.

Comment: I basically start by saving the contact list (with user details) on Firebase Firestore on sign up. I then loop the ContactList to get each user but omitting the current user from the list. I then populate the ContactList on a ListView. Have added this code above.

Comment: yes i understood but what you mentioned is different from my problem